# Java: How to disable button until even 1 RecyclerView items checkbox is checked?

Tags: java, android

I need to get my button to be disabled until the user checks a checkbox in RecyclerView.

My checkboxes are inside a RecyclerView and button is outside of it.

This solved the problem:
(I put the code which ONLY considers parts of this particular case)

Adapter:

```
public class NewGamePlayerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewGamePlayerAdapter.NewGamePlayerViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<NewGamePlayerItem> mNewGamePlayerList;
    private OnItemsCheckStateListener checkStateListener;

    private int checkedItems = 0;

    public interface OnItemsCheckStateListener {
        void onItemCheckStateChanged(int checkedItemCounter);
    }

    public void setOnItemsCheckStateListener(OnItemsCheckStateListener checkStateListener) {
        this.checkStateListener = checkStateListener;
    }


 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewGamePlayerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final NewGamePlayerItem currentItem = mNewGamePlayerList.get(position);

        /** In some cases, this will prevent unwanted situations **/
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        /** If true, checkbox will be selected, else unselected **/
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(currentItem.getCheckBox());

        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            /** set object's last status **/
            currentItem.setSelected(isChecked);

            if (isChecked) {
                checkedItems++;
            } else {
                checkedItems--;
            }

            checkStateListener.onItemCheckStateChanged(checkedItems);
        }
    });
```

Activity:

```
mAdapter.setOnItemsCheckStateListener(new NewGamePlayerAdapter.OnItemsCheckStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckStateChanged(int checkedItemCounter) {
                mNext = findViewById(R.id.button_next);

                if (checkedItemCounter == 0) {
                    mNext.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    mNext.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

First I tried to do Adapter part into the constructor, which obviously didn't work, then I only copy-pasted that same if-else from constructor into the holder, then it started working.

Comment: Your adapter may track if any items selected and then notify fragment or activity with button about changes. Post your code to provide more information about the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this situation is to make global variable `int checkedItems = 0;` in your adapter, and every time item is checked you do `checkedItems++;` or if it is not `checkedItems--;`. 
Now you need to tell that change to your activity. So in adapter you define interface for example

```
public interface OnItemsCheckStateListener {
    void onItemCheckStateChanged(int checkedItemCounter);
}
```

You will have to implement this interface into your activity, and define if (checkedItemCounter == 0) disable button, else enable it. Then you need pass that instance into adapter. So in adapter make global `private OnItemsCheckStateListener checkStateListener;` and setter (which will be called from activity)

```
public void setOnItemsCheckStateListener(OnItemsCheckStateListener checkStateListener) {
    this.checkStateListener = checkStateListener;
}
```

Et the end after every increment or decrement of checkedItems, you need to trigger `checkStateListener.onItemCheckStateChanged(checkedItems);`

Comment: I changed my post, which includes suggestions of yours, but I still didn't manage to make it work, so what I still need to do or change?

Comment: DId you override these functions in your adapter: onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType), onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position), getItemCount()? I mean, you still need to create regular adapter, and you need to add all that code that you pasted here in regular adapter.

Comment: I have no other adapter, this is the one where is everything else too, I just pasted code which only considers this particular problems peaces

Comment: I made it work now, thanks for your help m8, if you are interested in how I solved it, I changed my post to see the final version, again thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh great, glad I could help